# Threading module is very slow when behind uwsgi

Tags: python, uwsgi, python-multithreading

In a view I use the `threading` module to launch a task in the background and immediately return the view (I need to launch it in the background since I need to wait for the response of an I/O operation).

The thread that is run is a python function that takes almost no time (~0.1s) when run on its own but can take up to an hour when run using the `threading` module.

My app is a Django app running behind uwsgi. What is the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html),

> threads generated by your application will never run

Simply add

```
enable-threads  = true
```

to your .ini file or the `--enable-threads` flag when running uwsgi.

Comment: I note that this flag will not enable Python's multiprocessing module to work, and only allows the thread module to work correctly, for those of you who might be pulling your hair out at 3AM.